# Sybase standard mechanisms

Tags: logging, sybase

It is necessary to log changes to database objects. Now only the date of the last change can be seen. Are there any standard mechanisms for logging all changes?

Comment: keeping a history of changes ('auditing') typically consists of creating triggers that write historical info to a 2nd set of audit/history tables; assuming the RDBMS software you're using supports replication, another option would be to replicate all changes to another database where all DML statements (or the resulting data changes) are stored in audit/history tables; since auditing reqs can vary (eg, save entire row? save just changed values? keep track of user/application that made the change? keep track of change date/time?) there typically isn't a 'standard' out-of-the-box solution

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the slowly-changing dimensions, as a bulkier, but easy-to-access historical data warehouse.

Additionally, you can activate the auditing via:

sp_configure "auditing", 1

The latter would require you to install the audit system first, using the auditinit utility (which essentially adds an extra database, where all your audit records will be stored).